# Custom UITableViewCell with xib file and custom constructor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

One question about custom UITableViewCell.

I would to have a UICustomTableViewCell with the xib file to design this cell.

When I create my cell I would to use also a custom constructor to pass some parameters.. for example:

```
initWithMyParamterA:(NSString*) aParameterA andParameterB:(NSString*) aParameterB;
```

I would prefer not to use the properties to pass this parameters.

So, how can I implement this constructor together `loadNibName` (to load the xib file) and default constructor:

```
initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

How can I mix these? :)

Answer (score 1):

I've extended UIView class by a category, and added a method for creating XIB using a class name

```
+ (id) viewWithDefaultXib
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
return [topLevelObjects count] ? [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
}
```

You can define the following method in a class to initialise object.
    - (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
More info at  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Views unarchived from an xib will always be initialized using `initWithCoder:` you must override that method to initialize your custom view from a nib.

[Nib file docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/loadingresources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)